# Static methods working on instance fields

Tags: c#

I've seen static methods written (but I've never run the code) which uses instance data from another class (instance based).

Usually, instance data work with instance methods and likewise for static fields/methods. What is the implication of working on static data in an instance method? I'm assuming it is frowned upon but I can't find any details on what will happen under the hood. Also, what about instance methods working with static data?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean "What is the implication of working on instance data from a static method?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with static data in an instance method, the only implication I can think of is synchronization in a multithreaded application.  I can't think of any adverse implications when working with instance data from a static method.  However, just because something *can* be done doesn't mean it *should* be done.

Here is a concrete example you provided.

> Class A is instance based and has an
>   instance field called ProductPrice of
>   double. Class B is static and has a
>   static method called
>   PlayAroundWithPrice(double price), and
>   the coder passes in the ProductPrice
>   field.

Obviously, there is nothing technically *illegal* with this example, but it goes against the grain for me.  First of all, the ProductPrice field of Class A is obviously public since Class B can operate on it.  For the purposes of encapsulation, I personally always make fields private and use a public property to access them.  Second, because ProductPrice is a public field instead of a public property, there's no way for Class A to prevent ProductPrice from being set to invalid values (negative values, for example).  Third (as stated above), if this example occurs in a multithreaded program, there could be synchronization issues.  Fourth, I guess this is the real rub, why have a static method on Class B to operate on the field of Class A?  Why not put the static method on Class A?

I don't know that I'd go as far as making this a hard-and-fast rule (perhaps simply a rule-of-thumb), but I would restrict using static methods for when you do not want to pay for the cost of constructing an object just to use the method.

For example, in the project I work on, I have an IPHeader class that will fully construct an IPHeader instance from a byte buffer.  However, in most cases, I only need a couple of values from the IPHeader.  So to avoid the costs associated with creating and garbage-collecting an IPHeader instance, I added a couple of static methods that will extract the values from the byte buffer directly.

I hope I've understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem working on instance data from another object within a static method.

I assume that you mean, for example, passing an object's instance variable to a static method via a parameter, and that method then working on that variable.

Static just means you don't get **this**, but you could get **otherobject->something**

I don't think it would be any more frowned upon than just using a static method would be in the first place.

Comment: Hope I understood the question :)

Comment: Hi, I meant as in this: Class A is instance based and has an instance field called ProductPrice of double. Class B is static and has a static method called PlayAroundWithPrice(double price), and the coder passes in the ProductPrice field. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Ah yep, sounds very similar what I described above (passing an instance variable to a static method as a parameter). I don't think there's anything wrong with that, as long as you're satisfied with having the method static in the first place.

Comment: I am a little confused, though. FxCop says static methods shouldn't work on instance data, though?

Comment: Static methods do not have any access to instance data from their own object (because there is no object, hence no 'this').  They can access other objects fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem having a static method use object instances or an instance method using static data.

The framework is full of methods that demonstrates this. The very commonly used `String.Concat` method for example is a static method that takes one or more object instances. (A `Concat` method call is what the compiler produces whenever you use the + operator to concatenate strings.)

The `Int32.MaxValue` is a static property, there is obviously no problem using that in an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, instance methods has a hidden `this` parameter which is used to pass the instance the method is supposed to work on. This is the reason static methods cannot access instance data without explicit reference (as they cannot know which instance of object they should access).

Considering this, I don't see any special difference between static and instance methods. They are both methods and has more similarities than differences.

Both static data and instance data are prone to threading issues, however, instances are much less likely to be used between threads. As a consequence, accessing static fields might require more care (regarding syncronization issues).

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem.  Recently I had a scenario where I needed each instance of a class to have a different, but reproducible random seed.  I kept a private static int in the class, and incremented it for every instantiation, and used that as the seed.

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with using static data in an instance method but I think you need to really limit the types of data you use.  The advantage / disadvantage of this approach is that a single data change can alter the behavior of all objects of a particular type.  This makes changing that type of data very risky.  I tend to constrain uses of this to the following scenarios

1. Immutable values - Nothing can change so there is nothing to worry about
2. Global Objects - I **strongly** refrain from doing this but I've found that occasionally the evils of having a global object outweigh the risks.  These objects are carefully monitored though and heavily tested.